# place label aligned to right, at certain y coordinate?

Tags: gnuplot

I need to place a label at the right, above of a fitted average horizontal rule. I have an y-coordinate of the rule, but i don't know the coordinate of the right border of the graph.

I saw, I could use `at graph 0.5,0.8` syntax, only if the horizontal rule would be fixed, which it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use different coordinate systems for x and y values. The available coordinate systems are:

- `first`: value on the left and bottom axes.
- `second`: value on the right and top axes.
- `graph`: relative to the area within the axes, `0,0` is bottom left and `1,1` is top right.
- `screen`: relative to the entire canvas.
- `character`: depends on the chosen font size.

So, if your x-value should be relative to the graph, use `graph 0.5`, for the y-value you can use `first yval`:

```
set label at graph 0.5, first yval+ofs
```

Here, `yval` is the y-value of the horizontal line, and `ofs` is an offset in order to displace the label a bit.