# Placing timestamp at gnuplot defined positions (e.g., top center)

Tags: timestamp, gnuplot

I know gnuplot>>date = system ("date +%F") creates the timestamp, and one can use 'set label date at X,Y'. How can I place the timestamp at say, bottom-right, top-center etc., i.e., at gnuplot defined positions?

Answer (score 0):

The coordinates used for placing the labels can refer to different coordinate systems. In your case you can either use something like

```
date = system("date +%F")
set label date left at char 1, char 1
```

which places the date left-aligned at one character width from the left boundary and 1 character height from the bottom boundary.

You could also use absolute screen coordinates like

```
set label date left at screen 0.01, screen 0.02
```

Both for left-bottom. top center would be

```
set label date center at screen 0.5, screen 0.95
```

If the label should be centered with the plot instead of beeing centered with the image size, you can use `graph` coordinates:

```
set label date center at graph 0.5, screen 0.95
```

and so on.

See also e.g. [place label aligned to right, at certain y coordinate?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23180595/2604213) and `help coordinates` in the interactive gnuplot terminal.