# Is it possible to get the values for de y-axis in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot, unique-values

I need the calculated y-values by gnuplot. How do I get those values.
In this example, de values 100 and -700.

[image: Example]

I looked between all default variables gnuplot but could not find it.

Let me try to explain:

First an example
[image]

Here you can see the problems. I have the offset set to white into the column when possible en black out of the column. But that depends of course on the values
y-min and y-max. I think, when I have these values I can calculate the offset.
Now I have only a hard value;

```
"<tail -60 log.txt" u 1:(-($12)):($12>300 ? (-$12) : sprintf("")) w labels left font ",10" tc rgb "white" rotate offset 0,0.2 notitle,\
"<tail -60 log.txt" u 1:(-($12)):(($12<=300 && $12>0) ? (-$12) : sprintf("")) w labels left font ",10" tc rgb "black" rotate offset 0,-1.7 notitle,\
```

Maybe there is a trick or other solution?

Here example number 3.[image: Example 3]
I tried:

```
set terminal unknown
plot "<tail -60 log.txt" using 9:12
print  GPVAL_Y_MAX, GPVAL_Y_MIN
replot
```

And I get the values: 650,0 150,0 and they are
the values of column 12, thats ok but not the
values of the y-axis and only below the zero. (see example 3)
What do I wrong or do not understand?

Comment: That situation is quite tricky since the positioning doesn't depend only on the y-values but also on the selected font, font size, absolute plot size etc. I'm not sure if you can work out a universally applicable solution. If having the y-max and y-min values would help you, you still would have to use something like I proposed in my solution to get those values. But you don't need to run your full script. Possibly only using `plot 'file.txt' u 1:(-$12) w p, '' u 1:11 w p` would be enough to get the information.

Comment: Christoph, you show me the way and I found the (my) solution; `set terminal unknown
plot '<tail -60 log.txt' using ($9), '<tail -60 log.txt' using (-$12)  
y_above_zero = GPVAL_Y_MAX
y_below_zero = GPVAL_Y_MIN
print y_above_zero, y_below_zero
replot` gives the perfect values, **thanks again** very much. Now I 'm going to try to calculate the offset. Again, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

These values are the result of gnuplot's autoscaling. You'll have access to those values only *after* plotting via the variables `GPVAL_Y_MIN` and `GPVAL_Y_MAX` (type `show variables all` after plotting to see all available variables).

If you need those values for something in the plot you must plot to the `unknown` terminal first and then to your actual terminal:

```
set terminal unknown
plot 1.01*x

set terminal wxt enhanced
set label left at graph 0.1,0.9 sprintf('y_{max} = %.2f', GPVAL_Y_MAX)
replot
```

Comment: Then i am in trouble, i need those values to calculate the offset of the labels.

Comment: Well, then you should describe your actual problem. You know, that you can use differenct coordinate systems to position a label? http://stackoverflow.com/a/23180595/2604213