# Gnuplot - Labels cut off plot

Tags: bash, gnuplot

My x and y labels are cut off the pic

[image: see the plot]

I found the crop/nocrop option but didn't work.
How can I set a margin? and as you can see the titles (top right) are covered by the data. How can I set a margin there?

The following code comes from my bash script.

```
#set output
 set terminal png large size 1920,1080 enhance background rgb '$BKGD_COLOR' 
 set output '$PLOT_OUTPUT_DIR/BW_${ArrayFile[$j]}_$DATE.png'

 #set data
 set datafile separator ","
 set timefmt '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'
 set xdata time
 set format x "%d/%m/%Y\n%H:%M:%S"

 #set axis (new style named 11, disable top and right axis, disable tics on top and right)
 set style line 11 linecolor rgb '$TEXT_COLOR' linetype 1
 set border 3 back linestyle 11
 set tics nomirror font "/usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf,16" textcolor rgb "$TEXT_COLOR" 

 #set grid
 set style line 12 linecolor rgb '$TEXT_COLOR' linetype 0 linewidth 1
 set grid back ls 12

 #set line style
 set style line 1 lc rgb '$RCVD_COLOR' pt 1 ps 1 lt 1 lw 2 
 set style line 2 lc rgb '$SENT_COLOR' pt 6 ps 1 lt 1 lw 2 

 #set text
 set key font "/usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf,10" textcolor rgb "$TEXT_COLOR"          
 set title 'Bandwidth (Mbps)' font "/usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf,14" textcolor rgb '$TEXT_COLOR'
 #Removed - set ylabel 'Mbps' textcolor rgb '$TEXT_COLOR'
 set yrange [0:*]

#plot using the column 1 and 3 of the CSV file. with line points and title 'Bytes Received' and line style 1 (as defined above)
plot '$DIR/ResultsCSV/mg_bandwidth/${ArrayFile[$j]}.csv' u 1:3 w lp ls 1 t 'Bytes Received', '$DIR/ResultsCSV/mg_bandwidth/${ArrayFile[$j]}.csv' u 1:4 w lp ls 2 t 'Bytes Sent'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the font-size of your tics when setting the terminal. This size is used to determine the automatic margins:

```
set terminal png ... font ',16'
```

Alternatively you can set explicit margins with

```
set lmargin screen 0.05
set bmargin ...
```

For possible coordinate types, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/23180595/2604213

BTW: Use the `pngcairo` terminal which has a much better rendering quality.

Answer (score 2):

@Christoph provided the answer about the margin, but you asked about your key as well.

In order to fix that, you can put the key in a different position.  Doing

```
set key inside top left
```

will move the key to the left side, where the data won't cover it up.  You can also move it ouside the plot altogether with

```
set key outside top right
```

which will move it to the right side and outside of the plot where it won't be covered up.

See `help set key` for more detail.

Comment: That's cool. But do you know if I could remove the red and green line in the keys and keep just a small colored dot?

Comment: @CharlyRoch The key will match the style of the plot.  Thus as you used linespoints, the key will use that too.  You could plot the same data twice using lines and then again using points, suppressing the key on the first plot like `plot datafile w lines notitle, datafile w points title 'Example' lt 1` to make only points appear in the key.  You just have to specify the line type to make sure that they use the same one.  The plot will look the same as now, but you will only get the points on the key.

Comment: Pretty smart! But does not reduce the space between the legend and the point. I mean there is a big blank space like "legend_____dot" . Thank you

Comment: @CharlyRoch Look up the options under `help key`.  I believe that _samplen_ is what you are looking for.  Doing something like `set key samplen 1` will move that point much closer.

Comment: Great! I didn't understood samplen as a margin. Thanks